# Views Data Export Module hide button when unfiltered

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I'm using the Views Data Export module to export an Excel spreadsheet of search results from a View. The problem is that the button is still visible when the View is unfiltered, and the full export of several thousand records (on the fly) chokes the server. Is there a way -- through the Drupal admin interface, since I don't have server access -- to simply hide the "XLS" button when the full dataset is being displayed? Hiding the button when the search results are above a certain threshold count would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options, you can apply a default views filter that is applied on page load through the view settings.

You can also use javascript to test if all the filters are on "All" then hide the button with CSS